# Checkbox with watson

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I know that Watson is a powerful tool, but for different reasons I do not want to use all the power it offers. I want to know if it is possible to create checkboxes.
The idea would be to replace the users' text inputs with predefined choices.

I do not find anywhere to do that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If all you want to do is predefined options, then just use a web page.

Comment: I want use predefined options, just for five questions on my dialog. for example : select article of a restaurant menu.

Comment: I may have misapplied my question ... I want to add a button

Answer (score 0):

Use the **options** output.
You can do this through the web UI IBM provides and there the output looks like this:
[image]

When you open it with the JSON editor it looks like this:

```
{
  "output": {
    "generic": [
      {
        "values": [
          {
            "text": "Some text."
          }
        ],
        "response_type": "text",
        "selection_policy": "sequential"
      },
      {
        "title": "demo",
        "options": [
          {
            "label": "button1",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "1"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "button2",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "2"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "response_type": "option"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```